# Calculating charge when current is a piecewise function

Tags: charge

The current is defined as follows:\$\$

\$ i=\begin{cases} 
      4 & 0<t<1 \\
      4t^2 & t > 1 \\
   \end{cases}
\$

The goal is to calculate the charge from \$t=0\$ to \$t=2\$ s

What I've tried:
I've tried integrating both parts.

\$\int 4dt=4t+c\$
\$\int 4t^2dt=\frac{4}{3}t^3+c\$

Then I fill in \$2\$ in the second integrated equation and \$0\$ in the first equation, and I subtract.
I get \$\frac{32}{3}\$ coulombs as the answer, but I should get \$\frac{40}{3}\$ coulombs.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You goofed the integration.

\$ \int_0^1 4dt + \int_1^2 4t^2dt \\
= \rvert_0^1 4t + \rvert_1^2{4\over3}t^3\\
= 4(1) - 4(0) + {4\over3}(2)^3 - {4\over3}(1)^3\\
= 4 + {28\over3}\\
= {40\over3}\$

Answer (score 0):

From 0 to 1: 12/3 C

From 1 to 2: 4/3*(8-1) = 28/3 C

12/3 C + 28/3 C= 40/3 C

Comment: In general, we try not to give direct answers to homework questions, but rather try to guide the OP toward finding the solution on his own. We're trying to teach the *process*, not the *result*.